# Any Free open source WebGL editors?

Tags: html, gwt, open-source, editor, webgl

At first, I do apologize for my bad English.

Our development team is working on a project, written in GWT that provides users the collaborative environment. Users can work on different projects, including animation making, image editing, 3D structure modelling and so on. So we have to provide them proper editors. I just want to know, are there any free/paid open source editors, so that we can embed in our project?

It would be much better if the following specifications, are met:

·        Better to be html5 compatible to benefit from latest technologies

·        Can be webgl

·        Should be open source

·        Better to be java and gwt / or we should be able to wrap and use it

·        Be reliable

·        Support standard file formats

Comment: Are you talking about 3D model editors in WebGL environment or something else?

Comment: Hi there. Yes, I'm looking for open source web based editors, so we can use them inside our project. Our project uses WebGL and HTML5.

Comment: What do you want users to be able to edit? WebGL is a low-level API called by Javascript. Your best bet may be an open-source web-based Javascript editor... possibly with intelligent completion for WebGL identifiers (functions, etc.).

Comment: For example, users should be able to create a new animation project on line and work on it, and since project iss a collaborative environment, other users can edit or comment on their work. Actually, suppose we are looking for something like Maya, that runs in browser for animation, and something like Photoshop that runs in  browser and so on. It's important that all of these (separate) editors, should be web-based, so we can integrate them with our project. Using WebGL ,HTML5 and JavaScript is proffered, of course.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Well, this may not be quite what you're looking for, but maybe it's close: [3DTin](http://www.3dtin.com/)

It's a simple CAD that looks like Minecraft. According to [here](http://www.3dtin.com/static/credits.html), it's written in Javascript, mostly jQuery.

I don't expect you're going to get anything with the sophistication of Maya or Photoshop that's web-based. That said, the guys behind 3DTin seem to be into open source, so maybe you can extend it for what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's great. Any similar thing for animation editing ?  Again thanks.

Comment: If you want Maya-like animation tools, you can use http://Clara.io -- it is similar to both 3DS Max and Maya and runs in your web browser.

Answer (score 5):

**[Goo Create](http://www.gootechnologies.com/products/create/)** is a free browser-based 3D editor (WebGL/HTML5) that enables you to:

- Run Goo Create in your browser, drop existing 3D models and textures right in.
- Create interactive 3D games and apps without coding (you can also code in JavaScript if you like).
- Publish and share easily on the web, or use [CocoonJS by Ludei](https://www.ludei.com) to create a native iOS/Android app.
- Best of all - it's free for public projects!

http://www.gootechnologies.com/products/create/

Answer (score 2):

http://Clara.io is a free WebGL-based 3D modelling, animation and rendering tool that runs in your browser.

It can be used for:

- Creating characters, items and levels for game engines (like Unity3D, Three.JS, Babylon).
- Rendering photorealistic images.
- Data conversions between OBJ, 3DS, FBX, Collada, ThreeJS, BabylonJS and many others.
- Publish your scenes and animations for embeding in webpages similar to how you can embed YouTube videos.

It differs from 3Dtin in that it is feature fulled, it is similar to 3DS Max, Softimage, Maya in terms of features.  It differs from Goo Create in that it focused on creating 3D content, rather than games.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/akjava/BVH-Pose-Editor

The Above link is the perfect solution your requirements.
It is made in GWT. It is open Source :)